# How to use ARGV*,How do i implement command line argument in it

Tags: ruby

<<-doc
Modify the sum of times method for any number of time values passed to this method.
Eg: ("11:23:07","22:53:45","0:23:23","23:45:56") -> "2 day & 10:26:11"
("0:45:34","0:15:58") -> 01:01:32 ; ("11:23:07","22:53:45") -> 1 day & 10:16:52
doc

But i want it as 2
[/name]
[input]
"24:01:10" "10:30:50"
[/input]
[output]
"Invalid 24-hour time value"
[/output]

===

[name]
3
[/name]
[input]
"0:45:34" "0:15:58"
[/input]
[output]
"01:01:32" 
[/output]

puts sum_time("11:23:07","22:53:45","0:23:23","23:45:56`enter code here`")

Comment: require 'time'
def to_seconds(timestamp)
  timestamp.hour * 3600 + timestamp.min * 60 + timestamp.sec
end

def sum_time(*time)
   # initialize the variables
     total_seconds = 0
     time.each do |time_item|
         timestamp = Time.parse(time_item)
         total_seconds += to_seconds(timestamp)
     end
    sum_time_string = ""
    days = (total_seconds / (24 * 3600)).to_i
    sum_time_string = "#{days} day & " if days > 0
    sum_time_string += Time.at(total_seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end

puts sum_time("11:23:07","22:53:45","0:23:23","23:45:56")

Comment: Please format the code properly. The way you wrote is, the posting is not really legible. Also, I find it unclear what you are asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

How to use ARGV from your script :

```rb
require 'time'
def to_seconds(timestamp)
  timestamp.hour * 3600 + timestamp.min * 60 + timestamp.sec
end
def sum_time(*time)
  # initialize the variables
  total_seconds = 0
  time.each do |time_item|
    timestamp = Time.parse(time_item)
    total_seconds += to_seconds(timestamp)
  end
  sum_time_string = ""
  days = (total_seconds / (24 * 3600)).to_i
  sum_time_string = "#{days} day & " if days > 0
  sum_time_string += Time.at(total_seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end
puts sum_time(*ARGV)
```

The call :

```
ruby your_script.rb 11:23:07 22:53:45 0:23:23 23:45:56
```